# How to pass a path into a variable (Python)

Tags: python, csv, path, config, argv

at the moment my python projects opens a csv file through a "hard coded" file path.

`readFromCsv(filePath='home/vm/user/test.csv')`

My Python project are opened via the console like:

```
python myproject.py config.cfg
```

and depending on the config file, there are other paths to other csv files

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as input_file:
filePath = input_file.readline().rstrip("\n")
```

Is there a way to parse the file path to a variable that the following function call work?

`readFromCsv(filePath)`

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what happens right? are you getting any error?

Comment: I got it! The problem was, I had 'home/vm/user/test.csv' in the configfile. without the ' ' it worked.